# CMake couldn't find MatLab libraries, even though MatLab is detected

Tags: matlab, cmake

I have been trying to build [BlockFactory](https://github.com/robotology/blockfactory) and I keep getting following error when trying to build it.

```sh
PS F:\simconnect-monitor\blockfactory> cmake -S . -B build
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.17763.0 to target Windows 10.0.19044. 
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.16.27045.0 
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info 
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done 
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe - skipped 
-- Detecting CXX compile features 
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done 
-- Could NOT find Matlab (missing: Matlab_MEX_LIBRARY Matlab_MX_LIBRARY ENG_LIBRARY) (found version "9.10") 
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:165 (message):
    Could NOT find Matlab (missing: Matlab_MEX_LIBRARY Matlab_MX_LIBRARY   MX_LIBRARY) (found version "9.10") 

Call Stack (most recent call first):
   C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:458 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
   cmake/FindMatlab.cmake:1873 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
   deps/mxpp/CMakeLists.txt:45 (find_package)
```

As you can see, MatLab was detected but the correct library cannot be found. I have tried with CMake 3.18.14 and 3.22.3 with no difference. I am really loss right now honestly. I have posted an issue in the [BlockFactory GitHub](https://github.com/robotology/blockfactory/issues/68) but so far, it is still unresolved.

Comment: How did you install MATLAB?

Comment: @CrisLuengo I downloaded the official installer and uses the academic license I have. Eitherway, I was able to narrow down the issue to '_matlab_64Build' returning as false. This is weird since I have a 64-bit MatLab and in other build process, it seems that 32-bit system even though I have 64-bit windows 10.

Comment: Yeah, you definitely need to configure your build to make 64-bit binaries. The MATLAB libraries do not have 32-bit versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I found the solution. I am using VS2017. By default for VS2017, cmake makes 32-bit project. You have to pass `cmake -A x64` to force it to a 64-bit project. In addition to that, though, I have to force finfmatlab.cmake to only look for 64-bit library by basically setting `_matlab_64build` to always be true. Make sure you have 64-bit MatLab if you do this.

Edit: Alternatively, you can install VS2019 instead since it defaulted to 64-bit project.